# Getting unknown property: craft\fields\Dropdown::contentTable

Tags: craft4

I've upgraded to craft 4.3.1

Now I can no longer delete fields:

> 2022-11-16 14:02:47 [web.ERROR] [yii\base\UnknownPropertyException]
> yii\base\UnknownPropertyException: Getting unknown property:
> craft\fields\Dropdown::contentTable in
> /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:154

I also can't apply project configs because of the same error:

```
name@server [~/path]# ./craft project-config/apply
Applying changes from your project config files ...
- removing superTableBlockTypes.a16ee89e-f606-4b1f-8045-aa45b99eb72b.fields.9a972eb6-eddf-4404-ae66-4c754d9c75ca.settings.options.0.__assoc__.0 ... 
  - removing superTableBlockTypes.a16ee89e-f606-4b1f-8045-aa45b99eb72b ... 
error: Getting unknown property: craft\fields\Dropdown::contentTable
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the built-in field types, only Matrix fields have a `contentTable` property.

Guessing at some point, there was a Git merge conflict in your `config/project/` files and somehow a (former?) Matrix field’s `contentTable` property got included in a Dropdown field’s YAML config.

If you still have a database backup from before this error started occurring, you should be able to resolve this by restoring that backup and the previous `vendor/` files (revert `composer.json` and `composer.lock` + run `composer install`), and then run the following command:

```sh
php craft project-config/rebuild
```

Then attempt the update again.

Comment: I reinstated a backup, but everything esle was broken beyond repair. I found the matrix field and changed the label so I could save it and the field would be rewritten in the db. Then I saved it and rebuilt the project config.

A bit unorthodox. But it worked